# Simplifying PHP in woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress

I have reordered and changed the WooCommerce checkout fields with this:

```
//Reorder checkout fields   
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'reorder_woo_fields' ); 
    function reorder_woo_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields2['billing']['billing_first_name'] = $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_last_name']  = $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_address_1']  = $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_city']       = $fields['billing']['billing_city'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_postcode']   = $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_email']      = $fields['billing']['billing_email'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_phone']      = $fields['billing']['billing_phone'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_country']    = $fields['billing']['billing_country'];

    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_country'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'];
    $fields2['order']['order_comments'] =  $fields['order']['order_comments']; 
    $fields2['billing']['billing_first_name'] = array(
        'label' => __('First Name', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'required' => true
    );
    $fields2['billing']['billing_last_name'] = array(
        'label' => __('Last Name', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
            'required' => true
    );

     $fields2['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = array(
            'label' => __('First Name', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'required' => true
    );
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] = array(
        'label' => __('Last Name', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
            'required' => true
    );
    return $fields2;
}
```

Is there a way to combine and/or simplify this? It works great, but seems so long and complicated.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this one on http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "reorder_woo_fields");

function reorder_woo_fields($fields) {

    $billing_order = array(
        "billing_first_name", 
        "billing_last_name", 
        "billing_address_1", 
        "billing_city", 
        "billing_postcode", 
        "billing_email", 
        "billing_phone", 
        "billing_country"
    );
    foreach($billing_order as $field)
    {
        $billing_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
    }

    $shipping_order = array(
        "shipping_first_name",
        "shipping_last_name",
        "shipping_address_1",
        "shipping_city",
        "shipping_postcode",
        "shipping_country",
    );
    foreach($shipping_order as $field)
    {
        $shipping_fields[$field] = $fields["shipping"][$field];
    }


    $fields["billing"] = $billing_fields;
    $fields["shipping"] = $shipping_fields;

    return $fields;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_custom_css_on_checkout', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_css_on_checkout( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_first_name']['class'] = 'form-row-wide';
    $address_fields['billing_last_name']['class'] = 'form-row-wide';
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Comment: But this does not include the function  to make first and last name full width...

Comment: Try the edit and add other fields as well, i think you just need the class parameter in the array.

Comment: Then just add your code at the end of the code. A better way of doing this would be to hook into the checkout fields and hook your css classes. Checkout the edit. Similarly you will have to do it for shipping address as well.